# Tkinter: Button Opening Another Window (and closing the current window)

Tags: python, graphics, tkinter

I am creating a "definition-testing" type of program (user enters the word, part of speech, and synonyms for every word and then the program quizzes the user on said information).
In the final window (the quizzing window), I have a window-layout like this:

```
1/25 What is the definition of _word_? # number out of total + prompt
Definition: _entry_ # entry fields for information
Part of Speech: _entry_
Next Help Quit # buttons; 'Next' checks the info and goes to the next word 
# 'Help' shows the info and goes to the next word
# 'Quit' force-quits the program
Tries Left: 5 # how many tries before the info is shown
```

The problem I have is with the 'Help' button. Normally, by just entering wrong information 5 times, it will create the 'Help' window successfully; however, it still keeps the original word (the one that could not be answered), open. When this new window is closed, the new word will show up, but there will be two windows: new word + old word. Also, the 'Help' button itself raises an error:

```
>>> 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File _filepath_, line 455, in <module>
    main()
  File _filepath_, line 68, in main
    test(screenDim, test_dict)
  File _filepath_, line 451, in test
    root.destroy()
  File "C:\Python2.7.3\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1728, in destroy
    self.tk.call('destroy', self._w)
TclError: can't invoke "destroy" command:  application has been destroyed
```

Here is my `test` function (I trimmed a bit of the code so it is easier to find the problem):

```
def test(screenDim, test_dict):
    class TestWords:
        def __init__(self, master):
            w, h = screenDim[0], screenDim[1]
            rootW, rootH, xPos, yPos = int(float(w)/3), int(float(h)/4), w/2 - (w/6), h/2 - (h/8)
            self.frame = Frame(master)
            self.frameB = Frame(self.frame)
            self.frameE = Frame(self.frame)
            self.posE = Entry(self.frameE, width = 50, justify = CENTER)
            self.defE = Entry(self.frameE, width = 50, justify = CENTER)
            self.posE.grid(row = 1, column = 2, pady = 5)
            self.defE.grid(row = 2, column = 2, pady = 5)
            # there are a few other widgets/frames that don't pertain to this problem
            self.goButton = Button(self.frameB, text = 'Next', command = self.getInfo, width = 10)
            self.helpButton = Button(self.frameB, text = 'Help', command = self.getHelp, width = 10)
            self.quitButton = Button(self.frameB, text = 'Quit', command = self.quitBox, width = 10, fg = 'red')
            self.goButton.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 10)
            self.helpButton.grid(row = 1, column = 2, padx = 10)
            self.quitButton.grid(row = 1, column = 3, padx = 10)
            master.geometry("%sx%s+%s+%s" % (rootW, rootH, xPos, yPos))
            self.frameE.grid(row = 3, pady = 5)
            self.frameB.grid(row = 4, padx = rootW/4 - 60, pady = 5)
            self.frame.grid()
        def quitBox(self):
            import sys
            sys.exit('Program Terminated.')
        def getHelp(self):
            triesLeft = 0
            self.frame.quit()
            root.destroy()
        def getInfo(self):
            info = (self.posE.get(), self.defE.get())
            self.frame.quit()
            return info
    class GetHelp:
        def __init__(self, master):
            w, h = screenDim[0], screenDim[1]
            rootW, rootH, xPos, yPos = int(float(w)/4), int(float(h)/4), w/2 - (w/8), h/2 - (h/8)
            self.frame = Frame(master)
            self.frameB = Frame(self.frame)
            self.goButton = Button(self.frameB, text = 'Next', command = self.frame.quit, width = 10)
            self.quitButton = Button(self.frameB, text = 'Quit', command = self.quitBox, fg = 'red', width = 10)
            self.goButton.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 5)
            self.quitButton.grid(row = 1, column = 2, padx = 5)
            self.frameB.grid(row = 2, padx = rootW/4 - 20, pady = 5)
            master.geometry("%sx%s+%s+%s" % (rootW, rootH, xPos, yPos))
            self.frame.grid()
            # again, a few widgets were removed for brevity
        def quitBox(self):
            import sys
            sys.exit('Program Terminated.')
    n, words, reviewWords = len(test_dict.keys()), test_dict.keys(), []
    shuffle(words)
    for i in range(n):
        word, triesLeft = words[i], 4
        while triesLeft >= 0:
            root = Tk(className = ' Definition Tester')
            root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
            root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
            app = TestWords(root)
            root.mainloop()
            try:
                info = app.getInfo()
            except TclError:
                info = ('', '')
            if info[0] == test_dict[word][0] and info[1] in test_dict[word][1]:
                del words[i]
                root.destroy()
                break
            elif triesLeft == 0:
                reviewWords.append(word)
                root = Tk(className = ' Definition Tester')
                root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
                root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
                app = GetHelp(root)
                root.mainloop()
                break
            else:
                triesLeft -= 1
                root.destroy()
```

The program automatically shows the help window after there are 0 tries left. Thus, the 'Help' button sets `triesLeft` to 0. However, this does not seem to open the window. Thanks!

Comment: How are you invoking the `test` function?  I.E. with what arguments?

Comment: @SamMussmann `test` takes two arguments: `screenDim` and `test_dict`. `screenDim` is a tuple with the screen dimensions: `(width, height)`; `test_dict` is a dictionary formatted like this: `{_word_: [_part of speech_, [_synonyms_]], ...}`. It is called by the function `main` (this can be seen in the traceback). I am sure the issue does not lie in the function calling/argument passing because if I remove the 'Help' feature, it runs perfectly. Also, the function itself runs perfectly until the 'Help' feature is used.

Answer (score 2):

You need to re-architect your solution so that you only ever create a single root window and only ever run a single instance of `mainloop`. Instead of creating and destroying the root window over and over, create and destroy instances of `Toplevel`. Tkinter simply isn't designed to create and destroy multiple root windows.

Comment: How can I do this? I've never used the `Toplevel` widget.

Comment: Also, doing `root = Tk()`, `app = Toplevel(root)`, and finally `app.mainloop()` opens two windows... I only want one open. In my 'help' feature, I want it to close the current window and a new window, not open two windows.

Answer (score 1):

You gotta change the tkinter variable and quit the current window in the function and than open another

```
def new_window():
    current_tkinter_variable.quit()
    new_variable=Tk()
    #carry on
```